# How to filter by only the main categories and not the subcategories Search & Filter plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a Filter with Search & Filter plugin (wordpress)

```
do_shortcode( '[searchandfilter submit_label="Filter" types="checkbox" taxonomies="category"]' );
```

The problem is that in the filter all categories with their subcategories appear. I would like only the categories to leave. How could I do?

Thanks

Comment: go to plugin documetation or there help section question and you will get answer

Comment: I have gone to the documentation page and have not found anything. And there is no question and answer page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hierarchical="0"` to remove the subcategories.

http://docs.designsandcode.com/search-filter/#options